# Not sure how to express this situation

Tags: word-choice

I have 3 brothers and I am the youngest. I am writing an email in which I have to mention the brother who is immediately older than me. How do I say? Should I say, "He is immediately older than me?" That sounds incorrect to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with just saying *my older brother*—or ***one*** *of my older brothers*. Both of those statements will always still be true.

But if you need to specify one older brother as opposed to the other, you can do so by using their name or by saying something like:

> my older brother who is the closest in age to me
>   the youngest of my older brothers
>   my second-oldest brother

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to describe him as

> my next oldest brother

[Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22my%20next%20oldest%20brother%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) reveals plenty of uses of this exact expression in the sense of "immediately older".

Note however that this usage of "next" relates to the order or sequence of things, and its interpretation is therefore highly context-dependent.

> **next**
>   adverb
>
> 1. in the time, place, or order nearest or immediately succeeding
>
>    - *next we drove home*
>    - *the next closest school*

If you haven't already mentioned a brother, then *my next oldest brother* would usually be interpreted as "the brother nearest in age older than me", exactly as you intended. However, if you've already referred to a brother, then this creates an ambiguity, since *next oldest* could also be interpreted as *the following brother in the family order*.

For example, if you have five brothers of which three are older than you, and you've already referred to the most senior brother, then "my next oldest brother" is likely to be interpreted as the *second oldest* of the male siblings, rather than Brother #3. Indeed, if you've already referred to all three older brothers, then "my next oldest brother" would logically be Brother #4 who, in this example, is actually *younger* than you!

Answer (score 1):

My inference of the statement is as below:
"I have 3 brothers and I am the 4th child"

To refer to the brother immediately older than me:
Can we use "**My elder brother, who is younger than the other two**"

OR

"**The 3rd child, who is elder than me**"

PS: Mods, comments (if any) with detailed explanation.